# wxPython - Any disadvantage adding widget directly to the sizer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

To shorten my code i noticed that i could add an Widget directly to the sizer. This would help me to get some partds of my code a lot shorter.

At least for widgets I won't change later on like StaticText etc. there should be no problem to do it like this?

The code looks like this:

```
vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(pnl, label='TestText', style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT),flag=wx.ALL, border=15)
```

Are there any other disadvantages i havent found yet?

Comment: You have no easily accessed reference to these items, so altering them or binding an action to them, becomes problematical. If as you say you have no intention of accessing them later, no, it shouldn't be a problem, although it feels like you are prioritising saving typing over clarity.

Comment: Not especially saving typing, i have an GUI with a lot of TextCtrl and StaticTexts and at the moment (as a newbe) i am trying to find a good way to make my class simpler and focus on the important things i use later on like the TextCtrls etc. So some work on my basic knowledge.And thank you for your answer!